# org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: EMP_SAL#7736

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting attribute not binding error, this error is coming when i am chaining the dataframe transformation. The input file i am reading as file stream.
Is this a pyspark bug or my code issue ?
`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: EMP_SAL#7736.`

```
2019-03-13 15:25:53 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 101, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)

caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding tree: null
```

Comment: Please read this - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve